# is there a better way to query system tables across a clickhouse cluster?

Tags: clickhouse

We have a modest clickhouse cluster, ~30 nodes, and want to collect usage stats on it. We are hoping to do this using scheduled queries against the system tables, but using a normal query only get information on the one node you happen to be connected to, and creating a distributed table only works with the *log system tables. We can loop over the nodes, but don't want to do that. Is there a way to get all the instances of a system table, such as system.parts, in one query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Distributed tables works with any type of tables and clusterAllReplicas as well.

```
create table test on cluster replicated as system.processes Engine=Distributed(replicated, system, processes);


SELECT
    FQDN(),
    elapsed
FROM test

┌─FQDN()────────────────────┬────elapsed─┐
│ hos.mycmdb.net            │ 0.00063795 │
└───────────────────────────┴────────────┘


SELECT
    FQDN(),
    elapsed
FROM clusterAllReplicas(replicated, system, sessions);

SELECT elapsed
FROM clusterAllReplicas(replicated, system, processes)

┌─────elapsed─┐
│ 0.005636027 │
└─────────────┘
┌─────elapsed─┐
│ 0.000228303 │
└─────────────┘
┌─────elapsed─┐
│ 0.000275745 │
└─────────────┘
┌─────elapsed─┐
│ 0.000311621 │
└─────────────┘
┌─────elapsed─┐
│ 0.000270791 │
└─────────────┘
┌─────elapsed─┐
│ 0.000288045 │
└─────────────┘
┌─────elapsed─┐
│ 0.001048277 │
└─────────────┘
┌─────elapsed─┐
│ 0.000256203 │
└─────────────┘
```

Comment: When we tried this solution, we started getting errors like this one: <Error> default.parts.DirectoryMonitor: Code: 48, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Received from <redacted>. DB::Exception: Method write is not supported by storage SystemParts. Any thoughts on what we might be doing wrong?

Comment: @RichardRymer you cannot create Mat.View witch inserts or reads system.parts. Seems you can achieve your goal simply by enabling system.part_log

Answer (score 4):

It can be used [remote or remoteSecure](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/remote/#remote-remotesecure) functions that support multiple addresses:

```sql
SELECT
    hostName() AS host,
    any(partition),
    count()
FROM remote('node{01..30}-west.contoso.com', system, parts)
GROUP BY host

/*
┌─host──────────┬─any(partition)─┬─count()─┐
│ node01-west   │ 202012         │     733 │
..
│ node30-west   │ 202012         │     687 │
└───────────────┴────────────────┴─────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Interesting. I will have to experiment with this to see if it works on Superset.

Comment: Very cool. I did not know about this. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @RichardRymer np, I glad to help ;)

Comment: So this ended up being the most stable solution for us, though it involves a little more maintenance for scheduled queries.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, we ended up using materialized views:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW _tmp.parts on cluster main_cluster 
engine = Distributed('main_cluster', 'system', 'parts', rand())
AS select * from system.parts
```

Comment: Though this worked, we are pretty sure it caused a bunch of performance issues, namely insert latency went through the roof.